# WPF ListBoxItem with WrapPanel doesn't wrap when vertical scrollbar is visible

Tags: wpf, listview, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I have a WPF ListView containing multiple ItemsControl that have WrapPanels.
The items wrap as expected as long as there is no scrollbar visible. When there is a scrollbar visible, when the window becomes less wide, I can see the WrapPanel claiming vertical space for the items that need to move to the column to the left, but the items do not move. After scrolling using the scrollbar, the items do jump to the correct column.

Has anyone encountered this and does someone know a solution?

A movie clip would be more clear but in the pictures below I try to explain the steps and what happens. The code for the project is posted below the pictures.

**No scrollbar, wrapping works fine:**
[image: No scrollbar, wrapping works fine]

**No scrollbar, even narrower window, wrapping still works fine:**
[image: No scrollbar, even narrower window, wrapping still works fine]

**A scrollbar is visible, wrapping is still ok:**
[image: A scrollbar is visible, wrapping is still ok]

**A scrollbar is visible, screen is narrower, the green wrappanel shows that vertical space is claimed for the items that should move to the leftmost column, but the items do not move:**
[image: A scrollbar is visible, screen is narrower, the green wrappanel shows that vertical space is claimed for the items that should move to the leftmost column, but the items do not move]

**After using the scrollbar, the items jump to the correct column:**
[image: After using the scrollbar, the items jump to the correct column]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Wrapping.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="800" Width="600">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailReadOnlyTemplate">
        <Grid Width="75" Height="15" Margin="2" Background="Green"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MainObjectReadOnlyTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DetailObjects}" 
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DetailReadOnlyTemplate}"
                          Background="LightGreen">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MainObjects}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMainObject}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MainObjectReadOnlyTemplate}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Bisque"/>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();

        MainObjects = new ObservableCollection<MainObject>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MainObjects.Add(CreateMainObject(i));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MainObject> _mainObjects;
    public ObservableCollection<MainObject> MainObjects
    {
        get => _mainObjects;
        set
        {
            _mainObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private MainObject _selectedMainObject;
    public MainObject SelectedMainObject
    {
        get => _selectedMainObject;
        set
        {
            _selectedMainObject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private MainObject CreateMainObject(int n)
    {
        return new MainObject
        {
            DisplayText = "Main object " + n,
            Number = n,
            DetailObjects = GenerateDetailObjects()
        };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DetailObject> GenerateDetailObjects()
    {
        var detailObjects = new ObservableCollection<DetailObject>();

        for (var i = 0; i < Random.Next(2, 4); i++)
        {
            detailObjects.Add(new DetailObject
            {
                DisplayText = "Detail " + i,
                Value = GenerateRandomString(Random.Next(3, 8))
            });
        }

        return detailObjects;
    }

    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length).Select(s => s[Random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**The dummy objects:**

```
public class MainObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _number;
    public int Number
    {
        get => _number;
        set
        {
            _number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _displayText;
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get => _displayText;
        set
        {
            _displayText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DetailObject> _detailObjects;
    public ObservableCollection<DetailObject> DetailObjects
    {
        get => _detailObjects;
        set
        {
            _detailObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class DetailObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _displayText;
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get => _displayText;
        set
        {
            _displayText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does subscribing for ListBox's SizeChanged event and calling UpdareLayout() on it make any difference? Or more precisely name the WrapPanel and update its layout.

Comment: @shadow32 I tried UpdateLayout(), InvalidateArrange(), InvalidateMeasure(), InvalidateParentsOfModifiedChildren(), InvalidateProperty(ActualHeightProperty), InvalidateProperty(ActualWidthProperty) on just about everything in the visual tree, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that ListView is not very good at scrolling. After disabling the scrollbars on the outer ListView and wrapping it in a ScrollViewer, the inner WrapPanels and the contained items behave as expected. Took me a day to figure this out.